# {an/the} arrangement

Tags: articles, generic-noun-phrases

Which is correct:

> If we withdraw from the defense, you will need to **make arrangement** to pay for the fees and costs incurred by your attorney.

OR

> If we withdraw from the defense, you will need to **make an arrangement** to pay for the fees and costs incurred by your attorney.

OR

> If we withdraw from the defense, you will need to **make arrangements** to pay for the fees and costs incurred by your attorney.

Comment: As a native US English speaker, only the third sentence sounds correct to me.

Comment: I'm just thinking of modern US usage: "make arrangements" is a common idiom; while both "make arrangement" and "make an arrangement" sound a little odd in this sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the simpler phrasing:

> If we withdraw from the defense, you will need to arrange to pay for the fees and costs incurred by your attorney.

If you must use the construction with 'make', either singular or plural for 'arrangement' will be equally valid, depending on the number of transactions and agreements that would have to be worked out.

Answer (score 1):

To me, the usual way to write this is:

> If we withdraw from the defense, you will need to **make arrangements** to pay for the fees and costs incurred by your attorney.

In these situation the "arrangement" is often a multi-step process, so it would be considered plural.

If a singular "arrangement" is appropriate, that is OK but an article is needed.

> If we withdraw from the defense, you will need to **make *an* arrangement** to pay for the fees and costs incurred by your attorney.

The first example is incorrect.